# Регулярное выражение: проверить, что в поле одно слово

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, jquery, asp.net, javascript

Добрый вечер.
Подскажите как написать выражение со след условием:
-в поле может быть введено только одно слово, пробелы могут быть или не быть с начала слова и в конце
Сейчас использую:

```
/(\s+)([a-z]+)(\s+)/
```

Но выражение какое-то неоднозначное( в некоторых онлайн проверках работает, а в некоторых нет(. Плюс ко всему оно не отлавливает написание одного слова (перед словом и за ним могут быть только пробелы и никаких других символов, иначе поле не валидно). А написание

```
/^(\s+)([a-z]+)(\s+)$/
```

что-то в онлайн проверках не работает... Уже мозг свихнул
Подскажите плиз как правильно написать

Comment: В лоб же: `/^\s*(\w+)\s*$/`

Comment: Антон Лакотко спасибо большое за развернутый ответ:)сейчас его впихну)а до  твоего совета, вот к чему додумался:
^([\s]+)?([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+)([\s]+)?$

Comment: VladD
Мне регулярное выражение необходимо для того, чтобы в C# в классе модели таблицы на поле задать атрибут с условием согласно рег выражения). Вот как-то так:
[RegularExpression( @"\s*[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+\s*"),ErrorMessage = "Error")]]
public string Pole { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У твоего выражения не верно используются квантификаторы после \s вместо + ( которое означает 1 и больше ), нужно писать * ( от 0 и больше ). Т.е. чтобы твое выражение было успешным нужно чтобы в обязательном порядке в начале и в конце стояли пробельные символы ( пробел, табуляция )

Если нужно именно Слово да еще и русское, то выражение будет таким:

```
/\s*[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+\s*/ui
```

Тестировать PERL-регулярки легко на этом ресурcе http://www.quanetic.com/Regex

Для C# это регулярное выражение будет выглядеть так

```
\s*[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+\s*
```

Тестировать можно [здесь](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)

Answer (score 0):

А зачем регулярки?

```
var isGood = !s.Trim().Contains(' ');
```

Если нужно проверять и другие символы, чуть более сложно:

```
var isGood = s.Trim().All(char.IsLetter);
```

Comment: А табуляции, CR, LF?

Comment: @klopp: замечание принято, обновил ответ.